# R Tidytext and unnest_tokens error

Tags: r, text-mining

Very new to R and have started to use the tidytext package.

I'm trying to use arguments to feed into the `unnest_tokens` function so I can do multiple column analysis. So instead of this

```
library(janeaustenr)
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

original_books <- austen_books() %>%
  group_by(book) %>%
  mutate(linenumber = row_number(),
         chapter = cumsum(str_detect(text, regex("^chapter [\\divxlc]",
                                                 ignore_case = TRUE)))) %>%
  ungroup()

original_books

tidy_books <- original_books %>%
              unnest_tokens(word, text)
```

The last line of code would be:

```
output<- 'word'
input<- 'text'

tidy_books <- original_books %>%
              unnest_tokens(output, input)
```

But I'm getting this:

> Error in check_input(x) : 
>    Input must be a character vector of any length or a list of character
>    vectors, each of which has a length of 1.

I've tried using `as.character()` without much luck.

Any ideas on how this would work?

Comment: @42 turns out `austen_books` is a function in a package up on github, https://github.com/juliasilge/janeaustenr/blob/master/R/austen_books.R -I'm surprised myself...

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian Also up on CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/janeaustenr/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
tidy_books <- original_books %>% 
              unnest_tokens_(output, input)
```

with the underscore in `unnest_tokens_`.

`unnest_tokens_` is the "standard evaluation" version of `unnest_tokens`, and allows you to pass in variable names as strings.  See [Non-standard evaluation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) for a discussion of standard vs non-standard evaluation.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Seems like there is quite a bit reading up I'll need to do get a better handle of R.

Comment: We all have to start somewhere! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue. I solved this by specifying input as below:

```
unnest_tokens(input = "events", token = "words", "word")
```

with "events" is actually my column name.