# Unnesting Tokens in Character Vectors

Tags: r

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)
sk <- as.character(const.df$text[122])
sk <- unlist(strsplit(sk, "\n"))
sk <- data.frame(line = 1:length(sk), text = sk, stringAsFactors = 
FALSE)

sk <- sk %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
  count(word, sort = TRUE) %>%
  anti_join(stop_words)`
```

> Error in check_input(x) : 
>     Input must be a character vector of any length or a list of character
>     vectors, each of which has a length of 1.

I am unsure what the error is concerning, as I have made the text a character vector and specified the length as 1.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39217789/r-tidytext-and-unnest-tokens-error

Comment: Check out `sk` before you do the `unnest_tokens` step.  You need to change 'stringAsFactors' into 'stringsAsFactors'

Comment: This worked!  Thank you for your help and attention to detail!!